# how can I get the Precognitive badge

Tags: discussion

It says: 
Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase.

I entered to area 51, but found that askubuntu have ended the commitment phase long time a go.

I am frustrated. I don't understand this badge... Can you explain it better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This badge is given to users who essentially *sign up for the site before the site actually exists*. They don't actually sign up at this time, of course, because the site doesn't exist, but following a site during the proposal phase is a statement of intent.

Each site that isn't part of the trilogy (Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault) went through a proposal stage on Area 51, where the site was defined and people "followed" it. Once the site gained enough interest, it entered a commitment phase, and once enough people committed, it went into a private beta, followed by a closed beta. Until a site reaches the "beta" phase, it doesn't actually exist.

In order to earn this badge, you must follow the proposal before it enters commitment phase, which is not something you can do on this site now since it has been public for some while.

This entire process is covered in more detail on the [Area 51 Frequently Asked Questions Page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

In short: **You can no longer earn the precognitive badge *or* beta badge on Ask Ubuntu**.

Comment: ok then how some users got this badge in year 2013? see the link: http://askubuntu.com/help/badges/67/precognitive

Comment: Quite possible they followed the site but didn't sign up until that point? If you note, the people who got the badge after the site had launched don't have the beta badge. Take a look at [the stats on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu): 599 users committed, 51.6% signed up for beta - that remaining 48.4% still followed the proposal but didn't commit to the beta.

Comment: any official link please ?